Proving that function maximizer is the kth smallest value in list
Given positive integers $L_1\leq L_2 \leq \dots \leq L_n$, I'd like to prove that for any given $k=1,2,\dots,n$ the function $f(u,k)=ku - \sum_{j=1}^n\max\{u-L_j,0\}$ attains its maximum value for $u=L_k$. In other words, I'd like to prove that $\mathop{\rm argmax}_u f(u,k) = L_k$ for any $k=1,2,\dots,n$. It seems to hold empirically, but I'm not quite sure how to prove it.

Hint: you can calculate $f(u+1,k)-f(u,k)$ exactly.
